# CollectionView didSelectItemAt is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Repo: https://github.com/Metaxa007/RunPersonalRecord

I have a collectionView and wanna perform a segue by clicking an item.
The problem is, that didSelectItemAt is not getting called while i am clicking an item. I tried different simulators and a real device.
Although long tap for `contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt` work fine.

```
class RecordsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
      let configuration = UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil){ action in
          let delete = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(systemName: "trash.fill"), identifier: nil,discoverabilityTitle: nil, attributes: .destructive, handler: {action in
              self.deleteItem(index: indexPath.item)
          })
          
          return UIMenu(title: "", image: nil, identifier: nil, children: [delete])
      }
      
      return configuration
  }
  
  // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
  
  override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
      
      return 1
  }

  
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      
      return distancesArray.count
  }
  
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? RecordsCollectionViewCell {
          cell.setupCell(distance: distancesArray[indexPath.item])
          
          return cell
      }
      
      return UICollectionViewCell()
  }
  
  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      print("not getting called")
      performSegue(withIdentifier: showRecordsTVCsegue, sender: self)
  }
}
```

The cell looks like this:

```
class RecordsCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceTextView: UILabel!
    
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    
    func setupCell(distance: Int32) {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        
        if distance >= 1000 {
            self.distanceTextView.text = "\(formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: Double(distance) / 1000)) ?? "") km"
        } else {
            self.distanceTextView.text = "\(distance) m"
        }
        
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
    
}
```

I tried different solutions on SO, but none of them helped me.
For instance

```
        collectionView.allowsSelection = true
        collectionView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

And i also do not use gesture recognizer.

Comment: It's cell with some views like UIButton on it? How is your cell looks like?

Comment: i have only one label in it, that shows a distance.     @IBOutlet weak var distanceTextView: UILabel!

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski try removing these 2 lines just for a small check: `self.layer.cornerRadius = 25`, `self.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: unfortunately did not help

Comment: @ArtiomLemiasheuski do you have `RecordsCollectionViewController` embedded into another view controller?

Comment: it is one of the screens in the navigation controller

Comment: If you remove (comment out) your `contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt` func, does `didSelectItemAt` get called?

Comment: @DonMag i also tried without ```contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt``` but still had the same result

Comment: @DonMag if you want to try it out, i post the link to my repo

Comment: @gcharita if you want to try it out, i post the link to my repo

Comment: So, when you tap a cell, nothing happens at all? No selection color change?

Comment: @DonMag literally nothing happens when i tap a cell. Only when i long tap it

Comment: I grabbed your GitHub repo... something very odd that I can't figure out. When using `Debug View Hierarchy`, it shows your cells have embedded cells? Doesn't make sense... I deleted and re-built your `RecordsCollectionViewController` in the Storyboard and (after adding `didSelectItemAt` to the code), it works fine.

Comment: @DonMag i did not fully understand what u meant. But the answer below fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked your repo and found solution.

Go to recordsCell -> ContentView in xib and remove custom class **RecordsCollectionViewCell** like on screenshot.

[image]